# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Must declare the scalar variable "@foo".' when trying to delete a row, parameters are declared

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2017

I am recieveing a

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Must declare the scalar variable "@Original_intakeDate".'

error when ever I try to delete a row from a datagridview. I am using c# in visual studio 2017 and much of the code is auto generated (which is also why it is so messy).

Following the stack trace of the error I found where I believe to be where the problem is coming from

```
private void InitAdapter() {
    this._adapter = new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter();
    global::System.Data.Common.DataTableMapping tableMapping = new global::System.Data.Common.DataTableMapping();
    tableMapping.SourceTable = "Table";
    tableMapping.DataSetTable = "Clients Intake";
    tableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add("intakeDate", "intakeDate");
    tableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add("firstName", "firstName");
    tableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add("lastName", "lastName");
    tableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add("disability", "disability");
    tableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add("Employed", "Employed");
    tableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add("returningClient", "returningClient");
    tableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add("region", "region");
    tableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add("lengthSinceEmployed", "lengthSinceEmployed");
    tableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add("Resume", "Resume");
    tableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add("Age", "Age");
    tableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add("education", "education");
    tableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add("mainIncomeSource", "mainIncomeSource");
    tableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add("refferal", "refferal");
    tableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add("cm", "cm");
    tableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add("firstAppt", "firstAppt");
    tableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add("Notes", "Notes");
    tableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add("copingAndMovingForward", "copingAndMovingForward");
    tableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add("SSMA_TimeStamp", "SSMA_TimeStamp");
    this._adapter.TableMappings.Add(tableMapping);

    this._adapter.DeleteCommand = new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
    this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Connection = this.Connection;
    this._adapter.DeleteCommand.CommandText = @"DELETE FROM [dbo].[Clients Intake] WHERE (([intakeDate] = @Original_intakeDate) AND ([firstName] = @Original_firstName) AND ((@IsNull_lastName = 1 AND [lastName] IS NULL) OR ([disability] = @Original_disability)) AND (([Employed] = @Original_Employed)) AND ((@IsNull_returningClient = 1 AND [returningClient] IS NULL) OR ([returningClient] = @Original_returningClient)) AND ((@IsNull_region = 1 AND [region] IS NULL) OR ([region] = @Original_region))  AND ((@IsNull_lengthSinceEmployed = 1 AND [lengthSinceEmployed] IS NULL) OR ([lengthSinceEmployed] = @Original_lengthSinceEmployed)) AND ((@IsNull_Resume = 1 AND [Resume] IS NULL) OR ([Resume] = @Original_Resume)) AND ((@IsNull_Age= 1 AND [Age] IS NULL) OR ([Age] = @Original_Age)) AND ((@IsNull_education= 1 AND [education] IS NULL) OR ([education] = @Original_education)) AND ((@IsNull_mainIncomeSource= 1 AND [mainIncomeSource] IS NULL) OR ([mainIncomeSource] = @Original_mainIncomeSource)) AND ((@IsNull_refferal= 1 AND [refferal] IS NULL) OR ([refferal] = @Original_refferal)) AND ((@IsNull_cm= 1 AND [cm] IS NULL) OR ([cm] = @Original_cm)) AND ((@IsNull_firstAppt= 1 AND [firstAppt] IS NULL) OR ([firstAppt] = @Original_firstAppt)) AND ((@IsNull_Notes= 1 AND [Notes] IS NULL) OR ([Notes] = @Original_Notes)) AND ((@IsNull_copingAndMovingForward= 1 AND [copingAndMovingForward] IS NULL) OR ([copingAndMovingForward] = @Original_copingAndMovingForward)))";
    this._adapter.DeleteCommand.CommandType = global::System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@intakeDate", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime2, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "intakeDate", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null, "", "", ""));
    this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@firstName", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "firstName", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null, "", "", ""));
    this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@lastName", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "lastName", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null, "", "", ""));
    this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@disability", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "disability", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null, "", "", ""));
    this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Employed", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.Bit, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "Employed", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null, "", "", ""));
    this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@returningClient", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "returningClient", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null, "", "", ""));
    this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@region", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "region", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null, "", "", ""));
    this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@lengthSinceEmployed", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "lengthSinceEmployed", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null, "", "", ""));
    this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Resume", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "Resume", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null, "", "", ""));
    this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Age", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "Age", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null, "", "", ""));
    this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@education", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "education", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null, "", "", ""));
    this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@mainIncomeSource", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "mainIncomeSource", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null, "", "", ""));
    this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@refferal", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "refferal", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null, "", "", ""));
    this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@cm", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "cm", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null, "", "", ""));
    this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@firstAppt", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "firstAppt", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null, "", "", ""));
    this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Notes", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "Notes", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null, "", "", ""));
    this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@copingAndMovingForward", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "copingAndMovingForward", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null, "", "", ""));
```

I have already fixed a couple issues with this block so I know there is potential for even more issues there.

Comment: The first parameter in your `DELETE` query is `@Original_intakeDate`, the one mentioned in the error message.  You're not supplying a value for that parameter.

Comment: I'm an idiot, thank you @David, if you want to put that as an answer I would happily give you a check mark